# PHP Foreach array in array

Tags: php, arrays

I need make array in array. Like this:

```
$array = array(
    array("value" => 1),
    array("value2" => 2));
```

I've tried to code it:

```
foreach($labels as $stats => $label)
{
    $array = array(
        array($label, $registrations[$stats])
    );
}
```

But it prints only one array, how to fix it? I know my code is bad, but I'm newbie in PHP :( Or I must use while?

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration you should add new array to a result array:

```
$array = array();
foreach($labels as $stats => $label)
{
    $array[] = array($label, $registrations[$stats]);
}
```

Or if you want `key-value` array:

```
$array = array();
foreach($labels as $stats => $label)
{
    $array[$label] = $registrations[$stats];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, last question, is it possible to print every $array from new line?

Comment: If possible, how to? `$array[] = array($label, $registrations[$stats])."\n";` something like this not works

Comment: Nope, that's not possible. Why do you need this, once again for google chart?

Comment: yep, for charts.. :D

Comment: Just pass your ready data to a chart. Adding `"\n"` is just a visual improvement and javascript don't need it.

Comment: How to add custom value to array start? `$array[] = array("['Element', 'Density']");
     $array[] = array($label, $registrations[$stats]);` like this, but this not works propertly

Comment: Add this element before start `foreach`, it will be first.